# Python Variable Reset in Class

Tags: python, class, variables, reset

In my program I have setup two classes called game.py and player.py.
Both files call upon functions within the Player class (everything is imported properly), and in the game.py file all the information about the variables is printed. However, when a variable is updated from the Game class the new variable is printed fine, but when it is updated from the Player class it does not change. Instead, the variables printed are the ones from the **init** in the Player class.

For example

```
(in the Game class)
print player.health
player.health += 1
print player.health
```

will print

```
100
101
```

whereas if i were to do

```
self.health += 100 #(from within the Player class)
```

and then

```
print player.health #(from the Game class)
```

the output would be

```
100
```

note: the variables are being updated within the Player class but aren't being printed properly from the Game class. but I know they're being update in Player because the user still dies when health reaches 0 even though it's constantly displayed as 100

I believe the cause is the variables are all being reset to the
**init** variables in the Player class, but that wouldn't fully explain why the Game class can manipulate the variables permanently. Does it have something to do with self.?

Any help is greatly appreciate. Thanks!

edit: Adding the code where Game gets the player variable

```
purple("\n\nHealth: %d" % player.health)
```

purple is a function that turns the text purple, player is defined at the start of the class as

```
player = Player()
```

it is no longer defined in any other file

Comment: Where is the `Game` code getting its `player` instance? Could it be modifying a different instance than your other code?

Comment: the Game code is importing the game.py file I have where Game is the only class

Comment: I just saw however that in the Game class and in the Main class I've created player = Player() in both, so maybe it's creating two instances of all the variables?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely do it. You probably want to create just one Player instance somewhere and pass it between your other objects (e.g. initialize `Game` by passing it a `Player` instance, perhaps).

Comment: I deleted the player = Player from the main file, so now there is only one instance of Player and it's in the Game class, yet still the problem persists

Comment: Give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it would be much easier to help.

Comment: How might I pass the Player instance between classes between files? If I create the Player instance (player) in the game.py file under class Game, how would I send that instance to the file Player class in player.py?

Comment: Um, you shouldn't need a separate copy of the player in `player.py` if that's where the `Player` class is defined. Just call all the methods you have to call on the same instance, whether that's the one from `Game` or one you create somewhere else and pass to `Game`. If you want more details, you'll have to show us your code.

Comment: Ok passing the variable player to all the classes that used them worked, thanks a lot for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Python does not reset variables.

We can't know for sure what the problem is since you didn't show us the code where `game` acquires a `player`, but the evidence suggests that the player being updated with `self.health += 100` is not the same player that `game` is using.